# Maximum area enclosed by a string attached at fixed points

Tags: plane-curves

> Two fixed points A and B have a string of length L attached between them. Supposing that the string does not intersect the line segment AB, then the string and AB will form a closed figure. **What shape will the string form when this closed figure has the maximum possible area?**

If A and B are the same point, then it is well-known that the shape is a circle. A and B are moveable, then it has been shown elsewhere that the maximal-area shape is a semicircle: [find maximum area](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700600/find-maximum-area) .

My instinct says that when A and B are fixed (as in this question) the shape will be an arc of some circle with AB as a chord, but I would like there to be some sort of proof.

So far, I can argue that the maximal-area shape must be convex, since if it wasn't you could turn the inwards-facing bit outwards to make a bigger area without changing the length L.

Comment: See [Isoperimetric problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality) for some useful references in this vein

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I see a question in here? Though I do believe you're correct about the line segment will be serve as a chord of some circle.

Comment: The question is "what shape will the string form when the closed figure has the maximum possible area?"

Comment: Ok. Then I believe your solution is correct, though I don't recall the manner of proof.

Comment: [This older question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22584/) looks applicable

Comment: Yes. That is exactly my question. Thank you -- I searched but could not find the question I was looking for. Do you think I should delete mine then?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the protocol is either.